# What dangers lurk by un-defining proprietary compiler macros?

Tags: c++, macros, intel

In my C++ class, I have a private variable defined as

```
unsigned int _MT;
```

This worked fine until I tried using the Intel C++ compiler. When I used the Intel compiler (version 15.0.xx) I get the error:

```
... error: expected an identifier
      unsigned int _MT;
                   ^
```

Upon closer inspection, I discovered that Intel has a predefined (and proprietary) macro `_MT`. It's not entirely clear to me what this macro does. I do know that it is only defined for 64-bit architectures—which is pretty much every platform these days.

What danger is there in undefining this macro?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: I recommend you change your own code. The C++ standard has this to say in `17.6.4.3.2 Global names`: _Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace._

Comment: In other words, it's not Intel that's using a proprietary macro, the variable uses a reserved name format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a variable that starts with an underscore followed by a capital letter is *undefined behaviour*.

Don't do it.

(I've seen `_MT` standing for "use multithreaded runtime").